# Pandas - Identify if a date in a pandas column is falls on Saturday or Sunday

Tags: python, pandas

I want to identify if a date value is on a Saturday or Sunday. If it is, then I want to change said date to the friday prior. (example df and result df below - these are real dates from May 2019, as you can see there is a Saturday(5/4/19) and Sunday(5/26/19) date pulled into the week prior in the results df. The (5/2/19) date stays the same as it is a weekday not a weekend.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['5/3/19','5/4/19'],['5/3/19','5/2/19'],['5/24/19','5/26/19']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date1','Date2'])
print(df)


data2 = [['5/3/19','5/3/19'],['5/3/19','5/2/19'],['5/24/19','5/24/19']]
resultsdf = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Date1','Date2'])
print(resultsdf)
```

I am running this code for a Month to Date range. I have to have the code to group a large data set into a MTD view - but I am having trouble creating variables for a list of sat/sunday ( as there will be 8-10 weekend dates per month) Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd # added when using visual studio 
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().date())
day_of_week = today.dayofweek
last_monday = today - pd.to_timedelta(day_of_week, unit='d')
month_day = today.day
start_month_scope = today - pd.to_timedelta(month_day, unit = 'd')
first_day_of_month = start_month_scope + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit = 'd')
```

The problem with the code below is that is only works if I need to find the saturday & sunday on 7 day (M-f) period.

```
last_sunday = last_monday + pd.to_timedelta(6, unit='d')
last_sat = last_sunday - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')
last_fri = last_sunday - pd.to_timedelta(2, unit='d')
```

I need some variable to input to the code below:

```
finaldf.loc[(finaldf['Due_Date'] == last_sat), 'Due_Date'] = last_fri
```

So 'last_fri' would be just the most recent friday from the given saturday or sunday, so referencing my example df there is the 5/4/19 example which gets pulled back into a 5/3/19 (the last friday for that instance) or the 5/26/19 gets pulled back to 5/24/19. As you can see the code would have to understand first if the date is saturday and sunday then next what is the closest friday prior.

*** if all the above got confusing please just reference my df -> resulftdf ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a oneliner:

```
df.Date1 -= pd.to_timedelta(
    (df.Date1.dt.dayofweek - 4).apply(lambda v: v if v > 0 else 0), unit="D"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case using `BDay` with `np.where`

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
for x in df.columns:
    df[x]=np.where(df[x].dt.weekday.isin([5,6]),df[x]-BDay(1),df[x])

df
Out[623]: 
       Date1      Date2
0 2019-05-03 2019-05-03
1 2019-05-03 2019-05-02
2 2019-05-24 2019-05-24
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, if your feeling helpful lol, maybe help me with my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371256/sql-query-i-need-help-return-information-from-the-mock-table-provided :)

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this could also be possible:

```
finaldf['Due_Date'] = [x + pd.to_timedelta(4 - x.dayofweek, unit='d') if x.dayofweek > 4 else x for x in findaldf.Due_Date]
```